# Can't set TOP margin to buttonBarView using XLPagerTabStrip

Tags: swift

I'm using the library `XLPagerTabStrip` extending on my `Main ViewController` of `ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController`, and my problem comes that I can't add top margin to `buttonBarView`, it shows in top always. I need to add 64 top margin.

[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip

class MainVc : ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController{    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }   
}
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Why you can't add? please show us what you have tried

Comment: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/5/30/e138839e7e8d149d0538f77cc33d102d-full.jpg

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: I post example code, and image. Sorry for my first post and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`
use this code

**Solution:**
in appdelegate

```
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainVc())
```

the problem with you is you don't have navigationBar, so you need to pass this view from navigationController

Comment: in appdelegate "window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainVc())" do like this while going in this controller

Comment: the problem with you is you don't have navigationBar, so you need to pass this view from navigationController

Comment: "window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainVc())" -> Thats the solution, thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help you bro, please vote for this answer so that other could know the answer.

Comment: and L. F. bro don't be over smart cause your reputation is high. Have some common sense bro. Thankyou.

Comment: @HabinLama please [edit] your answer and move there explanation from comments. Consider removing this first line of code if it's not the correct answer (otherwise leave it but maybe write in what cases it should solve the issue)